# replace values by condition after group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

So I have a dataframe like the one below.

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3], 'categ':['A','A','A','B','C','A','A','A','B','C','A','A','A','B','C'],'cost':[3,1,1,3,10,1,2,3,4,10,2,2,2,4,13] })
dff

   id categ cost
0   1   A   3
1   1   A   1
2   1   A   1
3   1   B   3
4   1   C   10
5   2   A   1
6   2   A   2
7   2   A   3
8   2   B   4
9   2   C   10
10  3   A   2
11  3   A   2
12  3   A   2
13  3   B   4
14  3   C   13
```

Now i want to  make a new  grouped by 'id' dataframe and create a new column where if the sum of category A = 50% and B = 30% of the cost of C, then return True, otherwise false. My desired output is the one below.

```
     new    
id      
1   True    
2   False   
3   False
```

I have tried some stuff but i can't make it work. Any idea on how to get my desired output? Thanks

Comment: For `id = 1`, B is 33.3% of C not 30% ?

Comment: yes true, I just changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pivot data frame first and then check if columns `A`, `B`, `C` satisfy the condition:

```
import numpy as np

dff.pivot_table('cost', 'id', 'categ', aggfunc='sum')\
   .assign(new = lambda df: np.isclose(df.A, 0.5 * df.C) & np.isclose(df.B, 0.3 * df.C))

categ  A  B   C    new
id                    
1      5  3  10   True
2      6  4  10  False
3      6  4  13  False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `pd.crosstab` with `normalize`, then apply a little bit math.
Notice : here we can not use equal due to float, we need `np.isclose`

```
s = pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['categ'], df['cost'],aggfunc='sum',normalize = 'index')
s['new'] = np.isclose(s.values.tolist(),[0.5/1.8,0.3/1.8,1/1.8],atol=0.0001).all(1)
s
Out[341]: 
categ         A         B         C    new
id                                        
1      0.277778  0.166667  0.555556   True
2      0.300000  0.200000  0.500000  False
3      0.260870  0.173913  0.565217  False
```